# Almost sure convergence, product of variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

Consider the sequence of random variable given by distribution : $$\mathbb{P}(X_n=1)=1-\frac{1}{n},$$ $$\mathbb{P}(X_{n}=0)=\frac{1}{n}$$ and $Y_n=X_n \cdot Y$ for random variable Y. Does the $Y_{n}$ converge almost surely?

> **My attempts**:
>   $Y_n$ converges in probability to $Y$. What is more ${\{\omega : Y_n\nrightarrow Y\} }=\{\omega : X(\omega)\neq0 \wedge \forall n_0 \exists n>n_0 X_n(\omega)=0\} $ Now, for instance, when $\mathbb{P}(Y=0)=1$, we have almost sure convergence. Does the answer depend on the variable $Y$? I was also trying to show something about $\mathbb{P}(\forall n_0 \exists n>n_0 X_n(\omega)=0)$, but without independence of $X_n$ I have nothing.

Comment: Indeed, both situations are possible. Sure you were not told that $P(Y=0)\ne1$ and/or that $(X_n)$ is independent?

Comment: I was told that $(X_n)$ **don't have to** be independent and nothing about $Y$.

Comment: Then both situations are possible.

Comment: But how to show that if $(X_n)$ is independent and $P(Y=0)\neq1$, then the sequence does not converge? Is it true? :)

Comment: Yes it is true and it follows directly from Borel-Cantelli lemma.

Comment: Ok. From Borel- Cantelli lemma we have that$\mathbb{P}(\forall n_0 \exists n>n_0 X_n(\omega)=0)=1$, and then, becuse $P(Y=0)\neq1$, we have that the sequence does not converge. But what if we have that $P(Y=0)\neq1$ but nothing about independence?

Comment: Then both situations are possible (ter repetita).

Comment: Maybe there exists necessary and sufficient condition?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1325055/ Same class?

Comment: I haven't seen it! Probably yes...

Comment: Does your teacher know you are outsourcing your homework?

Comment: In fact it isn't our homework.